# FullCalendar.io eventDrop (span over midnight) determining which day was dropped on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

In the agendaWeek view it is possible to have a multi slot event and when you click the bottom of the event (not resize) and drag it to the start of a day. the result can be that the starttime is located on the previous day while the endtime is correct.  Alternatively, if I drag to the end of the day I can end up with the same result (event spanning two days).

My Problem is the later I want to truncate the endtime to midnight same day as start (I have the working), but when dragged to start of morning I want to be able to move the starttime to 00:00.  So how can I determine which day the event was dropped on?

I have found eventDragStop(event, jsEvent, ui, view), but how can I use jsEvent ClientX and ClientY to determine the day?  Or some other way to determine the day the mouse dropped on?

Comment: Can you give a more specific example with actual dates/times please? Your descriptive version is a little hard to follow, it would be easier to understand the issue with a worked example. It's not clear why you can't use the start/end times of the event to work out what the date is.

Comment: Set calendar configure to agendaWeek and intervalSlot="00:15".
Now open page and create and event that is from 1am - 2am e.g. 4 slots.
Next click and drag the event, but click on the event at the bottom e.g. in the last slot 1:45am - 2am.  Now drag to the start of the day and don't be specific e.g. part of the event should overflow before 00:00 hours.  E.g. drop only when the mouse point is on the 00:15am - 00:30am slot.
At this point you will notice that the event start is the day before where you dropped it. and the end is 00:30am on the day you dropped it.  E.g. it spans over midnight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In eventDragStop can use jsEvent.clientX to get the X mouse pointer coordinate position.

Then in eventDrop can compare drag stop clientX position to the event's start day's column right border position. Get the right border like this:

```
let x = document.querySelector(`[data-date="${event.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD')}"]`)

if(x) {
  let element = x.attributes['data-date'].ownerElement;

  let columnRight = element.offsetLeft + element.offsetWidth;
```

Then compare columnRight to the clientX position.  if clientX > columnRight then have determined that mouse drop was on the next day to what the event.start day is, and can then if desired change the event start to 00:00hrs.

Note: when moving events on fullCalendar the mouse pointer is not always on the same day as the event when dragging and dropping, you can move event to the left and the event will snap to a new day will the mouse is on the next day e.g. the snap get the mouse pointer out of sync with the event.  If using clientX with eventDrop in this case this needs to be considered.